# Reading files in nested loop in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I have a set of files.

```
file1, file2, file3
```

I need to read them pairwise in bash script using nested for loop.

```
file1, file2
file1, file3
file2, file3
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I can read all the files in a directory. 

for i in $(ls)
do
    for j in ...
done

in the second for loop I need to read files except $i.

Comment: Perhaps you should be more clear with the files you have, are there only 3 files? Or is each file read twice max or more? It's not clear what exactly you want. For example, is there a file4 and should it also be "file1, file4".

Comment: Yes, I have 98 files in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go through all combinations of two files in the directory:

```
flist=(*)
for i in "${!flist[@]}"
do
   file1="${flist[i]}"
   for file2 in "${flist[@]:i+1}"
   do
      echo "Files: $file1 $file2"
   done
done
```

`flist=(*)` creates an array containing the names of all the files in the current directory.

`for i in "${!flist[@]}"; do` starts a loop over the indices of the array `flist`.

`file1="${flist[i]}"` assigns the name of the i-th file in `flast` to the variable `file1`.

`for file2 in "${flist[@]:i+1}"; do` starts a loop over all the file names in `flist` starting the i+1-th file.

#### Example

Consider a directory with three files:

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file3
```

Now, let's run our command:

```
$ flist=(*); for i in "${!flist[@]}"; do file1="${flist[i]}"; for file2 in "${flist[@]:i+1}"; do echo "Files: $file1 $file2"; done; done
Files: file1 file2
Files: file1 file3
Files: file2 file3
```

Comment: @Chepner Thanks for fixing that typo!